# how can i make store a username in txt file without having the same username twice?

Tags: python, file, authentication, passwords

```
user = input("\nInput user's Login ID: ")
while True:
    password = str(input ("Input user's Password: "))
    rpass = str(input("Re-enter the Password: "))
    if password == rpass:
        file = open("username.txt", "a")
        file.write (user)
        file.close()
        break
    else:
        print("You have entered the wrong password, Try Again")
```

I want make a program where users can sign up with their username and password and it can be stored into a txt file. And the next person that is going to sign up won't be able to use the same username.

I renewed the code but the same problem happened, the previous username is not detected.

[image: still can't be detected]

Answer (score 0):

Every time you write to the file, it appends to the same line.

```
if data == user+ ":" +password:
```

This condition is never true as a result.

One possible solution is to add \n after every write.

```
file.write (user +" : "+ password +"\n")
```

And your condition would be

```
if data == user+ " : " +password:
```

Be mindful of whitespaces and other characters. It should be an exact match with this method.

Edit: You're checking whether the new username and password together are a match.
What you should be doing is matching user with `data.split(':')[0][:-1]` -

```
if data.split(":")[0][:-1] == user
```

This will collect the string till the ':' and truncate the trailing space.

Comment: I have changed it, but the same problem is still there.

Comment: @elliciarosalie update your question with the changes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `parse` module, you can run `pip install parse` and use this code:

```
import parse

pattern = '{[a-z][A_Z][0-9]} : {[a-z][A_Z][0-9]}'
lines = []
user = input ("enter username: ")
password = input ("enter password: ")
with open('username.txt', 'r') as f:
   line = f.readline()

   while line:
       u, p = parse.parse(pattern, line)
       lines.append((u, p))
       line = f.readline()

users = [ u for (u, p) in lines ]

if user in users:
   print(f'Username {user} is taken, please try again.')

else:
   with open('username.txt', 'a') as f:
      f.write(f'{user} : {password}')
      print(f'Username and password successfully created.')
```

[image: this is the output]

Comment: @elliciarosalie you can download parse from pypi.org: https://pypi.org/project/parse/

Comment: I am unable to use parse, do you have any other solution without needing parse?

Comment: There is a similar solution using regex: https://pypi.org/project/regex/ But I wonder if you are not allowed to use any non-standard libraries? Could you confirm if that is a requirement in your question? @elliciarosalie

Comment: @elliciarosalie I have finished the code for you by adding in the part which writes the new username to the text file, so the next time you create a username, it will have something to check against :)